# Change output of textbox based on button clicked Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic

Hi everyone I am new to visual basic and am making my first program from a book I just bought and would like to change the output of my textbox based on the button I click for example if button1 is clicked I would like it to say "You selected cheese.".  Here is my code.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.cheese

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.cookie

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.pretzel

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.peanut
End Sub


Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: assign your text to the TextBox's Text property in your click eventhandler.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.cheese
    TextBox1.Text = "You selected cheese."
End Sub
```